# describe the set $S(t) := B_n ∩\lbrace x ∈ \Bbb R^n : x_n = t\rbrace $ geometrically as a subset of $\Bbb R^{n−1}$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, measure-theory, volume

Let $t ∈ [−1,1]$, describe the set $S(t) := B_n ∩\lbrace x ∈ \Bbb R^n : x_n = t\rbrace $ geometrically as a subset of $\Bbb R^{n−1}$. Here $B_n$ denotes the $n$-dimensional unit ball.

That is, we need to identified the points of form $(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n−1},t) ∈ \Bbb R^n$ with the corresponding $(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n−1}) ∈ \Bbb R^{n−1}$ in the obvious way.

It seems to me that everything in high-dimensional space are quite special so I am worrying about if there exist some obvious way to do that.

So may I please ask if there are some known formula about this? Any help or reference would be appreciate. Or should we construct some formula for it? May I please ask for an answer?

Also I am considering about the volume: Once we have identified the set, may I please ask for the $(n−1)$-dimensional volume of the set $S(t)$? How can we express it in terms of $V_{n−1}$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is $B_n$ ?

Comment: @ajotatxe The n-dimensional unit ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, we have $|t|<1$. Else, the intersection is either empty, or a single point (namely $0,\ldots,0,t)$).

Once that is true, we are left with the inequality

$$x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2\leq1-t^2$$

This is an $n-1$-dimensional ball, but not a unit ball (unless $t=0$). Its radius is, in fact, $\sqrt{1-t^2}$.

As for its volume, do you know the formula for the volume of a $k$-dimensional ball of radius $r$?

Comment: Sorry the formula of volume of a k-dimensional ball is not given. But I am allowed to leave the answer in terms of $V_{n-1}$, so I guess maybe it can be deduced from an inductive argument.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $V_{n-1}$. Does that represent the volume of a ball?

Comment: Yes it is, it's the volume of the $n-1$-dimensional unit ball.

Comment: Ok, then it just needs to be scaled by an appropriate power of $r$. I think it's $r^{n-1}$.

Comment: May I please ask some explaination on it? Or it is just like the case in 3-dimensional space? But in 3-dimensional space, once we scale the radius by factor $a$, the volume is scaled by $a^3$. May I please ask what is special for higher dimension?

Comment: It's just the same. If you scale the radius of a $2$-ball (a circle) by a factor of $a$, the area (the 2-volume) is scaled by $a^2$. As you note, for the $3$-ball, we scale by $a^3$. For the $n-1$-ball, we scale by $a^{n-1}$

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for explaination.